# how to add custom taxonomy terms to main rss feed Wordpress 4.4?

Tags: wordpress, rss, custom-taxonomy

I'm wondering how to add custom taxonomies and their terms to the main RSS feed in WP 4.4.

I've tried:

```
function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']))
        $qv['taxonomy'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Issues',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Reissues',
            ),
        );
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

But it's not expressing any of the custom taxonomy terms in the RSS feed when i go to http://www.example.com/feed The names of the custom taxonomies are "Issues" and "Reissues"

I'm at a total loss. Thanks for your help!